# Why is the second css background bleeding through?

Tags: css, svg

I am using a double background in css. The first one is an arrow, the second is a gradient.

It works fine in firefox, but in chrome the arrow is narrower and the background is visible on the left and right sides, why?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cup8j/3/).

html:

```
<div id="up"></div>
```

css:

```
#up {
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1em;
    background: 
        url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60476509/up-arrow-waiting-top.svg') no-repeat,
        linear-gradient(to top,  #FF9400,  #FFF000);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
}
```

svg :

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="20.819946"
   height="16.14336"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.2 r9819"
   sodipodi:docname="up-arrow-waiting-top.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="22.627417"
     inkscape:cx="12.599289"
     inkscape:cy="16.296111"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer4"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1018"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     showguides="true"
     inkscape:guide-bbox="true" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer4"
     inkscape:label="background"
     style="display:inline">
    <path
       style="color:#000000;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ff9400;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible;enable-background:accumulate"
       d="m 0.03125,0.03125 0,16.125 20.8125,0 0,-16.125 -20.8125,0 z M 10.5625,0.5 l 9.75,12.46875 -4.9375,0 -0.03125,2.6875 -9.5625,0 0,-2.6875 -5.28125,0 L 10.5625,0.5 z"
       id="rect3877"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:label="arrow"
     transform="translate(-88.254623,-510.99503)"
     style="display:inline">
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4b72a7;stroke-width:1.10000002;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       d="m 88.754623,523.96021 10.05788,-12.46518 9.762067,12.46518 -4.95499,0 -0.0159,2.67818 -9.582457,0 0,-2.67818 z"
       id="path3811"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccc" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

(I can't combine them - the background is animated independently.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your svg: using subpixel values is always problematic:

```
   width="20.819946"
   height="16.14336"
```

You should adapt you svg and change that to integer values `width="20" height="16"` or `width="21" height="17"`.

2) CSS: `em` is a relative unit and depends on your base font size, the browsers use rounding when dealing with em. (1em = 16px, everything might be rounded, see [this table](http://pxtoem.com/) for more info) If you want to have reliable dimensions use pixel values instead. (Theoretically, something around `1.3em` should work if your svg is `21px` wide, but why not use directly `21px` instead?)

Comment: But why doesn't the background size scale it to 100%?

Comment: @SystemicPlural good question, I have no idea^^ Perhaps some buggy implementation.

Comment: I'm not using px because the whole design is based around ems so that everything scales if the base font size is changed. This is one of the last bugs I haven't been able to iron out.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the width of the svg to be exactly proportionate to the size I am using it (15 x 10) and this has solved the problem whilst still allowing me to use ems.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in chrome which does not allow it to stretch svg images as given [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104701)

see the comment [#20](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104701#c20)

> The height and width inside the SVG must be set in "px". "%" does prevent the SVG from working in Chrome.
>   preserveAspectRatio="none" must be included to make the CSS background-size work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `em` as width and height, which is a unit which is relative to the font used in browsers. Firefox and Chrome most likely render the fonts in different sizes, and therefore the same `em` value will result in different width.